# Visual Studio Output Window warn on compile in Debug configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there any way that I can display a custom message in my Visual Studio Output window after I compile?

I had an issue today where my project was successfully compiled and a `NuGet` package built and released - only to find that none of my new changes had been included in the `NuGet` package as I had been working in Debug config and the package picked up from `\bin\release\Output.dll`

I would like to display a custom message in my Visual Studio Output window when I compile in Debug configuration, ideally something along the lines of:

```
========== Rebuild All: 11 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
*** Warning - change to Release configuration before publishing ***
```

Comment: No.   Your build server (you do have one, right?) should be configured to automatically 'do the right thing'.

Comment: Hi Neil, unfortunately I don't have a separate build server.  This is an ad-hoc project that I am maintaining and haven't set up a CI pipeline.

Comment: Even for small ad-hoc projects, I would still recommend creating some sort of CI pipeline.  Check-in, run your unit tests, build a release.  If you are creating nuget packages, I would say it's even more imperative.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll look into getting something set up this week.  This discussion is getting slightly off topic though - do you know if there is any way to add a custom message to Visual Studio Output window after I run a compile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Build events. See Project > Properties > Build Events menu.

Write Post-build event command line:

```
echo "*** Warning - change to Release configuration before publishing ***"
```

Comment: Fantastic, that's just what I was after!